# I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jxmpp.util.cache.LruCache exception in my project

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack

I am getting `NoClassDefFoundError` exception at below line,

```
XMPPconfig = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
```

And I have searched in many site but did't get solution for it. So please help me to resolve this issue. Below I am attaching debug snaps.

[image]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xyz.myapp_alpha"     
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 21
    versionName "1.79.1004"

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
dexOptions {

    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}
```

repositories {

```
mavenCentral()
maven {
    url "http://dl.bintray.com/journeyapps/maven"
}}
```

dependencies {

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile project(':weekcalendar')
compile 'com.github.johnkil.print:print:1.2.2'
compile project(':MPChartLib')
compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
compile project(':library')
compile 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:1.7.8'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.0'
compile project(':agendacalendarview')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile project(':xCLCharts')
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:2.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-legacy:2.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-integration:2.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.0.1'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3'
compile project(':qreader')
compile project(':cropper')
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.9'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.9'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.9'
//    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
//compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-resolver-javax:4.1.9'
```

// compile group: 'org.jxmpp', name: 'jxmpp-util-cache', version: '0.4.1'}

Comment: I have used below gradles ,
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.9'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.9'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.9'

Comment: Can you add your whole Gradl file to the question. Are you including the org.jxmpp lib?